# Running application with administrator privilege

Tags: vb6

I have made an application that copy the vb components to the system32 folder of the windows and register those components with “regsvr32”. It works well in Window XP, but in Windows Vista and Windows7 it can’t perform its task without right clicking the application .exe file and selecting “Run as administrator”. Is there any code in vb that automatically allows the application .exe file to run as administrator?

Comment: Create a proper installation package.  What you are doing is normally considered *very bad form*.  You aren't doing any version checking before overlaying existing libraries, nor are you incrementing usage counts.  Just don't do this.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have used the OS checking mechanism. What I really want to know is that, is there any way to run the application without selecting "Run as administrator"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do precisely what you ask you can add an application manifest that specifies an execution level of "requireAdministrator" within it.  However this means the application will *always* run elevated, and the user will also have to provide admin credentials or approve elevated execution for every run (UAC prompt).

Please just do things the right way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to second Bob's excellent comment above and suggest that you use a tool like Inno Setup http://www.jrsoftware.org (it's free) to build a proper installer.  One of the benefits of using a proper setup tool is that the setup application can request to  the OS to run with administrative privileges without using external files and manifests to make that happen.  The setup.exe that you build will have the necessary code built in to ask the OS for elevated privilege.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7, we can go to the properties of the file or an application exe file and then "Compatibility" tab. Then check the "Run this program as an administrator". 
It will force the application to be executed under the administrator privilege.
I used this and my problem was solved.