# Inno Setup Creating a shortcut to a HTA with administrative rights

Tags: inno-setup, uac, hta

I'm using Inno Setup to create a desktop shortcut that opens an [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) file saved in Program Files on Windows 7. This HTA file calls an external exe file that needs to run as administrator.

So, to do this, I want to automatically create a shortcut that runs as admin using Inno Setup. The problem here is that the shortcut points to an HTA file instead of an exe. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: HTA is HTML application. It's basically a script. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that shortcuts to documents (which is what an HTA probably counts as) can't run as admin.  I would be extremely dubious about an HTA that wanted to do anything admin anyway -- HTAs are typically just packaged webpages, aren't they?

Comment: True. I use an HTA because I don't need to create a complicated GUI. The HTA updates the content of itself by calling an external exe which overwrites the HTA file. That's why I need admin right. I think I should just place it directly under C:\some_folder so I don't need to mess with this.

Comment: If your executable needs admin access, it should be marked as such with a suitable manifest (there are too many suitable questions in the sidebar panel to list). This will then allow the Windows Shell to ask the user to confirm before running it. This should not be done for the initial `HTA` shortcut.

Comment: Note that the "Run this program as an administrator" check box on the "Compatibility" tab is different from the "Run as administrator" check box when you click the "Advanced" button on the "Shortcut" tab. The point is that you can configure a specific shortcut to run as admin, which is what would be needed in the case of an HTA (as it would indeed be inappropriate to mark mshta.exe as requiring elevation).

Comment: "If your executable needs admin access, it should be marked as such with a suitable manifest (there are too many suitable questions in the sidebar panel to list)." The problem with this comment is that the executable that runs an HTA is mshta.exe. We can't change the manifest for mshta.exe, so this answer is a complete non-starter. The correct way would be to configure an individual shortcut that is either 1) set to run as administrator or 2) run an executable (or script) that itself provokes the UAC prompt. That is the context and purpose of my answer to this question.

Comment: @AbqBill The questioner says it calls another executable that needs admin access. That is the entire premise for HTA running as an admin, so it can run the other executable as admin.

Comment: This depends entirely on whether you actually can change the executable's manifest. If not, then you're back to the same problem.

Comment: I would also point out that you can simply use code like that listed in elevate.js (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx) from inside the HTA to run the executable elevated, in which case there would be no need to 1) create an shortcut to run mshta.exe elevated or 2) add a manifest to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

check this sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA Helpomatic</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
     ID="oHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTAHelpomatic"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
<!-- ID="objHTAHelpomatic" -->
<!-- WINDOWSTATE="maximize" -->

</head>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

If HTAElevate() = True Then
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mmc.exe compmgmt.msc", , True
    Call Main()
End If

Sub Main()
    MsgBox "HTA-Ende", 4096
End Sub


'*** v13.3 *** www.dieseyer.de *****************************
Function HTAElevate()
'***********************************************************
' http://dieseyer.de/scr/elevate.hta
' Unter Windows x64 laufen VBS' nach einem Doppelklick in der x64-Umgebung
' mit %WinDi%\System32\wscript.exe oder mit %WinDi%\System32\cscript.exe.
' In der x64-Umgebung laufen VBS aber nicht (richtig). Die Prozedur
' HTAElevate() erkennt dies und startet ggf. das VBS in der

  Const Elev = " /elevated"

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5016 :: "

' Trace32Log "5018 :: oHTA.commandLine: ==" & oHTA.commandLine & "==", 1

  HTAElevate = True

' If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5022 :: "
  If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then Exit Function


  On Error Resume Next
    window.resizeto 750, 10 ' : window.moveto screen.width / 2, screen.height / 2
  On Error GoTo 0

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5030 :: "

  createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", oHTA.commandLine & Elev, "", "runas", 1

  HTAElevate = False

  self.close

End Function ' HTAElevate()


</SCRIPT>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The direct answer to the question is to create the shortcut to mshta.exe with the HTA's filename as its parameter. The shortcut to mshta.exe can be marked to run as administrator.

Comment: *"...can be marked to run as administrator."* May I ask you, how ?

Comment: That probably depends on the tool used to create the shortcut. I don't know whether the Inno Setup tool has this capability or not. An alternative is to use an external script (such as elevate.js, mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx) or elevate32.exe/elevate64.exe (http://www.westmesatech.com/misctools.html) to provoke a UAC prompt when starting an executable.

Comment: The "run as admin" will be a property of the executable, NOT the shortcut. Marking it as run as admin will have the side effect of making every other attempt to use it prompt to elevate.

Comment: I'm not talking about the "Run this program as an administrator" check box on the "Compatibility" tab. I'm talking about the "Run as administrator" check box when you click the "Advanced" button on the "Shortcut" tab. They are two separate options and have different effects. The point is that this option might not be exposed in the tool being used to create the shortcut. This can be worked around by calling a script or another executable that provokes the UAC prompt.

Comment: @AbqBill Noted. That doesn't change the fact that it should be the application that requires admin access asking for elevation though.

Comment: "That doesn't change the fact that it should be the application that requires admin access asking for elevation though." That's usually correct, except in this case mshta.exe is the executable (which is part of Windows). So hence we will either need to 1) Mark the individual shortcut to run mshta.exe elevated or 2) provoke the UAC prompt using some other means. The elevate.js script or elevate32.exe/elevate64.exe accomplishes option 2).

Answer (score -1):

If your executable requires admin access, then you should [add an appropriate manifest to your executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451408/588306), not try and elevate the HTML application.

Comment: This is dependent on whether you actually can change the executable's manifest. If not, you're in the same situation as needing to elevate mshta.exe.